# Get a URL from a HTML src Tag without URL parameters

Tags: php, regex

I have this content in a variable named for example `$iframe`

```
$iframe='<iframe title="Example Iframe" width="640" height="360" src="https://example.com/mypage?parameter=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

And I need to strip everything except the src URL without parameters

In the example above something like this should be the final result:

```
echo $iframe;

https://example.com/mypage
```

I'm not sure if there is a function to search for properties within a HTML string and then maybe use some regex to strip out the parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regexp

```
/src=\"(.*?)(\?.*\"|\")/
```

example [here](https://regex101.com/r/sJzhM8/2). Working php example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a27d9548a79dd53b39730e6d9cbf31e4841a06a)

```js
<?php

$re = '/src=\"(.*?)(\?.*\"|\")/';
$str = '\'<iframe title="Example Iframe" width="640" height="360" src="https://example.com/mypage?parameter=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>\'';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches[0][1]);
```